# Supremum norm on the space of measures?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $C\equiv C([0,1];\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the space of all continuous paths in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\|x\|:=\sup_{t\in[0,1]}|x_t|$, and denote by $M_C$ the vector space of all signed (Borel) measures on $(C,\|\cdot\|)$. Clearly, we can define

$$\tag{1}\|\mu\|_\infty := \int_{C}\!\|x\|\,|\mu|(\mathrm{d}x) \quad \text{ for each } \mu\in M_C,$$

where $|\mu|$ is the total variation of $\mu$.

(So that, for example, $\|\mathbb{P}_Y\|_\infty= \mathbb{E}[\sup_{t\in[0,1]}\!|Y_t|]$ for $Y=(Y_t)_{t\in[0,1]}$ a continuous stochastic process in $\mathbb{R}^n$.)

I was wondering if (1) defines a norm on $M_C$ whose name you know?

Comment: As defined, it is not a norm: $\|\mu\|_{\infty}$ could be negative.

Comment: Thanks, edited @PeterMorfe